# WooCommerce API authorization not working in node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm trying to create an app using WooCommerce API.

**index.js**:

```
var WooCommerceAPI = require('woocommerce-api');
// var WPAPI = require('wpapi');
var querystring = require('querystring');

var WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
  url: 'http://shop3.adinweb.ir',
  consumerKey: 'ck_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  consumerSecret: 'cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  wpAPI: true,
  version: 'wc/v2',
  queryStringAuth: true
});

WooCommerce.get('products?page=1', function(err, data, res) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(res);
});
```

The result:

[image: result]

I'm sure the `consumerKey` and `consumerSecret` are correct. I have tried many times :|

Please guide me. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You logging out the wrong thing I suppose? Should be:

```
console.log(data)
```

You must log out the data and not the response.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the [woocommerce package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/woocommerce) and it works fine with 2 changes.

1. Instead of "consumerSecret", use plain "secret"
2. In the "apiPath", use "/wp-json/wc/v2"

With these 2 changes the plain "woocommerce" package works like a charm.